# ASIHTTPRequest Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I have the following code in my cellForIndexPath but the pics are not in the right order:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.picturesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];;
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I will change my answer then, since you changed the question entirely. :-) ]

So... images in the wrong cells?

Cell re-use is likely the issue. You're starting an asynchronous process to load an image for a cell. If that cell scrolls off the screen, that cell object will likely be re-used for another cell that comes into view. Meanwhile, the first image being loaded will continue to be loaded, unless you can notice that the cell has been re-used and/or cancel the previous load.

Are the images appearing in the wrong order when you scroll? Or, does this happen if you just launch the app and do not scroll the table?

Comment: sorry updated question, the pictures are now loading but not exactly the correct ones.  Perhaps I need to move `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];;` outside of the block?

Comment: When I just launch the app and don't scroll, the images for the cell son screen are correct, only when i scroll does the order mess up.  It quickly sets the image to the correct one after a second or so. Perhaps I have to load a dummy image or something?

Comment: No, that wouldn't help. I think you really need to subclass UITableViewCell so you can have the cell know, if and when its `prepareForReuse` method called and stop loading and/or not display any image it had been loading.

Comment: Ah! That confirms that the issue is cell re-use. You have to be able to detect that.

Comment: Couldn't it be because its reusing a cell, and since it isn't populating data into it immediately, it will use the cached cell contents.  Putting in a dummy image if one is not available will not help?

Comment: That's the other side of what I've been suggesting. By implementing your own subclass, and the `prepareForReuse` method, you can do two things: cancel any download in progress, and set the image to nil (or a placeholder image). Cell re-use is EXACTLY what the problem is, which is what I suggested to begin with.

Comment: Ok, cool so I have to mess with the subclass then?  I already have a UITableViewCell subclass that I'm using.

Comment: Exactly. Have a look at prepareForReuse.

Comment: I tried searching for it but don't see anything that shows me how to implement this into the UITableViewSbuclass.

Comment: It's a (void) method in which you do whatever you think you need to do to prepare the cell to be re-used. In this case, what you want to do is cancel any active image download, and perhaps set the image to nil. Check the docs for UITableViewCell.

Comment: Ok, so I set image to nil and now its blank while i scroll while the image downloads, but the problem is, even if i scroll back to the top, the images are blank and are being redownloaded.  so it keeps downloading even the images i have already downloaded before if i went out of screen.

Comment: Of course. Now you need to figure out how to cache the image data you download so you don't have to do it twice. Did you think this was going to be simple? :-)